# How to 'show/hide' specific JSON Objects (TimelineJS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, timeline.js

- I am using Timeline JS with JSONP as my source file.
- The final product will be one timeline about two separate histories (which are related).
- I need to be able to show/hide each history's timeline elements so that you can view one and not the other.
- Default, of course, shows both histories simultaneously.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: which timeline js plugin? there seem to be several plugins named like that.